# Android: How do I stop Runnable?

Tags: android, runnable

I tried this way:

```
private Runnable changeColor = new Runnable() {
   private boolean killMe=false;
   public void run() {
       //some work
       if(!killMe) color_changer.postDelayed(changeColor, 150);
   }
   public void kill(){
       killMe=true;
   }
};
```

but I can't access `kill()` method!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Instead implement your own `thread.kill()` mechanism, using existing API provided by the SDK. Manage your thread creation within a [threadpool](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29), and use [Future.cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) to kill the running thread:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Runnable longRunningTask = new Runnable();

// submit task to threadpool:
Future longRunningTaskFuture = executorService.submit(longRunningTask);

... ...
// At some point in the future, if you want to kill the task:
longRunningTaskFuture.cancel(true);
... ...
```

Cancel method will behave differently based on your task running state, check the API for more details.

Comment: If `longRunningTask` contains a list of tasks, how can I abort certain task's execution? There may be lots of thread running concurrently.

Comment: @DanielWilson I have a same problem. did you solve that?

Comment: .cancel method not found

Comment: @Alston This is possible but you need to keep track of references. A list won‘t work, because of the return value of `void run()`. Collections do not store null. You could probably use a `Map<Runnable, Future<?>` to accumulate references to each Runnable when you `submit(Runnable)` them. Alternatively, you could use a Callable+Collection, because the Callable can return something other than null.

Answer (score 20):

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateThread);
```

Comment: please, try to describe answer

Comment: This is the easiest way for me.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be the proper answer, as you don't have to create your own custom Runnable with all the yada-yada in it or use the ExecutorService. That's what the `removeCallbacks` method is there for. It's the closest to a JavaScript `clearTimeout`, same pattern.

Comment: This will only cancel pending runnables that have been posted to the thread queue. It will not stop the runnables which are already running.

Answer (score 16):

```
public abstract class StoppableRunnable implements Runnable {

    private volatile boolean mIsStopped = false;

    public abstract void stoppableRun();

    public void run() {
        setStopped(false);
        while(!mIsStopped) {
            stoppableRun();
            stop();
        }
    }

    public boolean isStopped() {
        return mIsStopped;
    }

    private void setStopped(boolean isStop) {    
        if (mIsStopped != isStop)
            mIsStopped = isStop;
    }

    public void stop() {
        setStopped(true);
    }
}
```

class ......

```
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public void onStopThread() {
    mTask.stop();       
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mTask);
}

public void onStartThread(long delayMillis) {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mTask, delayMillis);
}

private StoppableRunnable mTask = new StoppableRunnable() {
    public void stoppableRun() {        
                    .....
            onStartThread(1000);                
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you realize this implementation leaves your Runnable burning up CPU cycles?

Answer (score 3):

`changeColor` is declared as `Runnable`, which does not have a `kill()` method.

You need to create your own interface that extends `Runnable` and adds a (public) `kill()` method.

Comment: If I create a new class then the compiler says there is problem with "color_changer.postDelayed(changeColor, 150);" - changeColor cannot be resolved to variable.

Comment: No; I mean interface.  However, making a non-anonymous class would also work.  Do you mean `this`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Non Anonymous class @SLaks

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO: I mean a regular named class, as opposed to an anonymous class.

Answer (score -1):

## You can Use this way

**Stop Runnable Thread**
//==============================================================================

```
 ThreadUtil.startTask(() -> {
                        // doTask
                    }, 1500);


//==============================================================================
 public class ThreadUtil {

        private static Handler handler;
        private static Runnable runnable;

        public static void startTask(IThreadTask iThreadTask, long delayTime) {
            stopTask();
            handler = new Handler();
            runnable = () -> {
                iThreadTask.doTask();
            };

            if (handler == null || runnable == null) {
                return;
            }

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayTime);

        }

        public static void stopTask() {
            try {
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                handler = null;
                runnable = null;

            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("ThreadUtil:","Error:"+e.toString());

            }

        }


        public interface IThreadTask {
            void doTask();
        }


    }
```