# How to stop Runnable in Android that's looping using postDelayed()?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, postdelayed

I need to stop a `Runnable` from running when an image is clicked in my Android app. I'm running this `Runnable` repeatedly using `ImageView.postDelayed()`:

```
r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        imgview.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
        i++;
        if (i >= imageArray.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
        imgview.postDelayed(r, 20); // set to go off again in 3 seconds.
        // imgview.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

};
imgview.postDelayed(r, 20); // set first time for 3 seconds
```

But under certain conditions I want to stop it from running, after it's already started. Here's the full code for my activity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        int i = 0;

        ImageView imgview, imgview2;
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable r;
        MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
        int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.f1, R.drawable.f2, R.drawable.f3,
                R.drawable.f4, R.drawable.f5, R.drawable.f6, R.drawable.f7,
                R.drawable.f8, R.drawable.f9, R.drawable.f10, R.drawable.f11,
                R.drawable.f12, R.drawable.f13, R.drawable.f14, R.drawable.f15,
                R.drawable.f16, R.drawable.f17, R.drawable.f18, R.drawable.f19,
                R.drawable.f20, R.drawable.f21, R.drawable.f22, R.drawable.f23,
                R.drawable.f24, R.drawable.f25, R.drawable.f26, R.drawable.f27,
                R.drawable.f28 };

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.tapp_activity);

            imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.water);
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);



            imgview2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            imgview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                    if(i==0)
                    {
                    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    i=1;
                    r = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            imgview.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                            i++;
                            if (i >= imageArray.length) {
                                i = 0;
                            }
                            imgview.postDelayed(r, 20); // set to go off again in 3 seconds.
                            // imgview.setOnClickListener(this);
                        }

                    };
                    imgview.postDelayed(r, 20); // set first time for 3 seconds
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    i=0;

                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    imgview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tapstill);
                    }



                }
            });


        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroy();
            mMediaPlayer.stop();

        }



    }
```

What can I change in my code so that my `Runnable` stops running in the `else` condition of my `onClick()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do I stop Runnable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458097/android-how-do-i-stop-runnable)

Comment: @patryk.beza that's not a duplicate of this question. See the accepted answer. I'll try to edit the question so it's clearer what's being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try removing the callback.

```
imgview.removeCallbacks(r);
```

In order for this to work, though. you'd have to ensure that `r` is the same `Runnable` as the one you posted.  You could do this by creating it once, possibly in `onCreate`.  Since the `Runnable` doesn't have any dependency on the `ClickListener` anyway, this shouldn't be a problem.

You might also need to do some synchronization in order to prevent the case where you're removing a currently running callback, though, now that i think about it.  The `volatile boolean running` idea is probably less complex overall.

Answer (score 2):

You can control your `run()` method with a boolean flag:

```
boolean running = true;
 ...

r = new Runnable()
{
         public void run() 
         {
             if(running)
             {
                 imgview.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);
                 i++;
                 if (i >= imageArray.length) {
                     i = 0;
                 }
                 imgview.postDelayed(r, 20); 
             }
         };
}
```

If you set `running = false` later on, your thread will be idle and that's what you want.

Comment: while loop can't stop  dear

Comment: @AmitPrajapati no it's if condition. it has been a while that I edited my answer.

Comment: where i want to use running false

Comment: Can u tell how when i need to restart this Runnable than what i want to do

Comment: @AmitPrajapati if you set _running = true_ thread will continue to run.

Answer (score -3):

You can do it by

```
         Thread.stop();
```

Comment: No, you can't. See: [Java documentation on Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29)

Comment: Besides the fact that [`Thread.stop()` is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), where's the Thread to stop?

Comment: (1) `Thread` is the class.  You can't just `Thread.stop()`; `stop` is not static, and thus requires an instance.  One you don't have a reference to.  You could presumably say `Thread.currentThread()` within the Runnable to get such a reference, but (2) the thread being stopped is not the current thread; otherwise, you could just return.