# How can i stop runnable thread in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

i am using a postDelayed thread, i need to stop that thread when i press back button. PLease anyone help me for that. Thanx in Advance.

This is my thread:

```
music1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
          music1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animationmusic1();
        holemusic1();

    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do I stop Runnable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458097/android-how-do-i-stop-runnable)

Answer (score 7):

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Declare `Runnable runnable` as a instance variable. Then

```
runnable =new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         music1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         animationmusic1();
         holemusic1();
    }
    };
music1.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
```

Then in `onPause`

```
music1.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Answer (score 2):

add an `onBackPressed()` in YourActivity  :

```
/** (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onBackPressed()
     */    
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        music1.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. When answering questions, please make sure that your answer isn't already covered by another one, especially since the answer was posted long ago. Thanks!