# Android, terminate threads when activity paused or stopped?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have an activity like below. I want the threads inside the activity terminate when the activity is paused or stopped. I searched and found volatile Boolean solution which didn't work for me. When i put the activity in pause or stop state, download continues, which i don't want it.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
//some code here
   private void foo(){
   new Thread (new Runnable (){
      @Override
      public void run() {
          //download something from internet
      }
}).start();
}
}
```

i used this pattern which didn't work:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
volatile Boolean state = true;
//some code here
   private void foo(){
   new Thread (new Runnable (){
      @Override
      public void run() {
        while (state) {
          //download something from internet
      }
   }
}).start();
}
@Override
public void onPause(){
super.onPause();
state = false;
}
@Override
public void onStop(){
super.onStop();
state = false;
}
}
```

Comment: You have to do it manually. *"download something from internet"* can be implemented in a lot of different ways, show yours.

Comment: Create a variable: Thread t; that will be globa to the class

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458097/android-how-do-i-stop-runnable) one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458097/android-how-do-i-stop-runnable

Comment: Then t = new Thread..... And I'm sure that there is overrided method onActivityEnd or something like that... There you terminate your thread with t...

Comment: @DeBanana: I can't define threads as fields because i have a lot of threads which are not necessarily used in every app session. So this can make the app memory insufficient.

Comment: @Gidi Sprintzin: clearly my class structure is far different from the examples you provided. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the structure of a thread which stops when back is hit, which I made for my game (and works). One key difference is you're using a thread in your Activity, while in mine I call a View in my Activity and run the thread in the View. If I hit back, I return to my Activity, and can call the thread again by hitting 'start.' BECAUSE my thread behaves the way you want yours too, even if it's happening in View, I thought you may find it helpful.

Where my of my synchronization happens is with the touchscreen values, and making sure those are updated in the thread and calling function.

The thread is trashed totally unless you have a way of saving the state (if you need to).

Your thread will need to synchronize with other functions you want controlling/sharing values with the thread, like onPause, etc..

**you'll need to have some synchronized test value inside your while loop which can then change state to false, otherwise the thread will continue on its own, which is the point of threads.

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private final GameActivity gameActivity;
private GameThread _thread;
private boolean previouslyRunning = false;
private int width;  //Screen width
private int height; //Screen height



private boolean newGame = true;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    this.gameActivity = (GameActivity) context;
    _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    width = w;
    height = h;

    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    //_thread.initialize();
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!previouslyRunning) {
        _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
        _thread.initialize();
    }

    _thread.setRunning(true);
    _thread.start();
    previouslyRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    //TODO - this was an Auto-generated method stub...
    //TODO - research what this might be useful for
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    //Put stuff that needs destructed here.

    boolean retry = true;
    _thread.setRunning(false);
    while (retry) {
        try {
            _thread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // will will try again and again
            //TODO: figure it out....
        }
    }

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    int numPointers = event.getPointerCount();
    int ptrIdx = 0;


    int touch = event.getActionMasked();

    if (touch == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        while (ptrIdx < numPointers) {
            int id = event.getPointerId(ptrIdx);
            float xp = event.getX(ptrIdx) / width;

            if (xp > 0.6) {
                _thread.shieldFront = false;
            }

            if (xp > 0.6 && !attacks) {
                attacks = true;
                _thread.attackandDefendToggle(true);
            } else if (xp > 0.6 && attacks) {
                attacks = false;
                _thread.attackandDefendToggle(false);
            } else if ((xp < 0.4 && xp > 0.2) && !movedRight) {
                movedRight = true;
                _thread.moveRight(true);
            } else if ((xp < 0.4 && xp > 0.2) && movedRight) {
                movedRight = false;
                _thread.moveRight(false);
            } else if (xp < 0.2 && !movedLeft) {
                movedLeft = true;
                _thread.moveLeft(true);
            } else if (xp < 0.2 && movedLeft) {
                movedLeft = false;
                _thread.moveLeft(false);
            }
            ptrIdx++;
        }
    }

    if (touch == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        _thread.moveLeft(false);
        _thread.moveRight(false);
        _thread.attackandDefendToggle(false);
        attacks = false;
        _thread.shieldFront = true;
    }



    return true;
}

class GameThread extends Thread {

    /****************************
     * Public functions       *
     ****************************/

    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView panel) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _panel = panel;

        // put sounds here.
        soundPool = new SoundPool(20, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        //more sounds later
        //TODO: create sounds
    }

    /************************************************
     *  update() function updates all variables,    *
     *  such as physics, Canvas draw points, score  *
     *  life, etc.. It is called before draw.       *
     ************************************************/
    private void update() {
        // all the values I want updated with each callback

    }

    /************************************************
     * draw() function creates images on screen,   *
     * but it performs no logic.              *
     ************************************************/
    private void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (canvas == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Draw stuff on screen
    }

    public void initialize() {
        // Values I want the program to start with;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    //Code below actually runs the thread.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {

                    // Update the game state
                    update();

                    // Draw image
                    draw(c);
                }

            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state

                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```